# How to change port GitLab on CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, gitlab, centos6

I tried to change port number on these files. But when I run **`gitlab-ctl`** reconfigure for updating. I can't access my link (`http://myaddress.example:8790`) Those files which I changed are:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml

/opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf

/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/attributes/default.rb

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml

/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf
```

In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` I change `external_url "http://myaddress.example:8790"`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you opened the port in your firewall?

Comment: I have opened all port in firewall :((

Comment: Please provide your distribution, installation method and servers (ruby and HTTP) you are using. If you are following any tutorial, please add it too.

Answer (score 0):

Using GIT_LAB_PATH as you gitlab base directory (the root where is it installed)

- Modify  `GIT_LAB_PATH/gitlab/gitlab.yml`

> ```
> ## GitLab settings
> gitlab:
> ## Web server settings
> host: HOSTNAME
> port: HTTP_PORT
> https: false
> ```

- If you use non-standard ssh port you need to specify it

  ssh_port: SSH_PORT
- Modify  `GIT_LAB_PATH/gitlab-shell/config.yml` to use the new HTTP port:

Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls. Should end with a slash.

```
gitlab_url: "http://HOSTNAME:HTTP_PORT/"
```

- Modify `/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab`

  listen *:HTTP_PORT default_server; # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
- Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for

```
Port SSH_PORT
```

- Restart SSH, restart GitLab, restart nginx:

  sudo service ssh restart
  sudo service gitlab restart
  sudo service nginx restart
- Test GitLab:

  sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
  sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
- Update the remote origins for your repos to use the new port:

> ssh://git@HOSTNAME:HTTP_PORT/repo_name

Answer (score 0):

Dear all I missing open port in firewall
I type it on linu terminal

> ## /etc/init.d/iptables stop

It worked