# GitLab 7.4.3 HTTP-Code 500: Could not connect to Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab

I installed GitLab with the omnibus installer and now i have the problem that i become a http error 500 when i try to go on the website. I use nginx as webserver and gitlab is reachable under the port 8000.

This is the error message i have in the production.log:

```
==> ./gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/" for 212.227.35.68 at 2014-11-14 10:15:07 -0600

PG::Error (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):

activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `connect'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in  `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:inn`restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
unicorn-worker-killer (0.4.2) lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:51:in `process_client'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
unicorn (4.6.3) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Here my nginx default page configuration:

```
server {
    listen   8000; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }
}
```

And the gitlab.rb config file:

```
# Change the external_url to the address your users will type in their browser
external_url 'http://gitlab.domain.com:8000'

# External URL to reach the GitLab CI Coordinator at
ci_external_url 'http://ci.domain.com:8000'
```

Everything runs on an Debian 7 server and i installed the actuall gitlab version 7.4.3.
After the installation process i modified the gitlab.rb an startet the reconfigure for gitlab
`gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. After that i started gitlab with `gitlab-ctl start`.

**Edit:** 
I have tested to open the website for the CI but there are the same error messages.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859660/change-port-gitlab-on-centos-6-not-successfully If it only happens on a custom port, add it to the title.

Comment: No that doesn't helped me. The error is the same and the firewall makes no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for this problem but i created a new problem.
First the solution:

The gitlab installation search for the file under `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` and i can find the file under `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` so i created a link with `ln -s /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` and now the error doesn't appear anymore.

The next error says that there are no gitlab user for postgresql but i have created one. Look this post:
[Gitlab 7.4.3: PG::Error Peer-Authentifizierung fehlgeschlagen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961517/gitlab-7-4-3-pgerror-peer-authentifizierung-fehlgeschlagen)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, found a more drastic approach that worked for me:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop

mv /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql.bak

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl start
```

Since the PostgreSQL files are 'corrupt' in some way, Gitlab just regenerates them. All my old data (settings, users, repositories and comments) is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you db server. Rails app tries to access if via Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Show you PG settings and database.yml
Probably PG listens only TCP sockets, but not UNIX. You should configure it.

Comment: Database.yml: 
`# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run 'sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure'.

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 10
  username: 'gitlab'
  password:
  host:
  port: 5432
  socket:`

Comment: So you should edit your database.yml to use tcp, with host and port from Gitlab settings

Comment: When i set it to tcp postgresql can't start anymore.

Comment: Show your database.yml

Comment: `# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run 'sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure'.

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 10
  username: 'gitlab'
  password:
  host:
  port: 5432
  socket: 'tcp'`

Comment: Is there anything in rails log, when you start app with PG listening via top?

Comment: The error messages in the rails log are the same as without tcp.

Comment: Well, it means that rails app still trying to use Unix socket instead of top